# product quantity is not added more than one product in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, quantity

In magento1.9 If I will try to add product more than 1 item then item is added in cart only 1 item.
I have checked admin configuration is fine but I am unable to to add more than one items in cart.

please help me if any one have this solution.